# Ubuntu Server 12.04 + Wine + Filezilla FTP Server help

Tags: wine, filezilla

I am not very experienced with non-windows operating systems, so please if you can answer, consider me to be a complete newbie with this.

I have a Ubuntu Server 12.04, I installed Wine on it so I could install some familiar programs with GUI on my Ubuntu.  I installed Filezilla Server using Wine, that went fine, the server is running, but I cannot find the GUI anywhere.   I know it is running because in the winefile, if I execute the filezille server.exe, it says it is already running.  However I have not been able to configure anything on the filezilla server because I can't see it anywhere.

What am I missing?

Comment: You should create an answer telling people how you solved it. Help improve the community by letting others trying to do the same as you, know how.

Answer (score 1):

Ubuntu Server has no GUI, and Wine does not ruin without a GUI (Xorg). Therefore I am puzzled how you managed to get this working in the first place.

Second, why would you want to run an FTP server using Windows software on a Linux platform? There are numerous FTP daemons available for Ubuntu, software that has been widely used for years, proven software.

I strongly recommend you take a look at the [Server Guide](https://help.ubuntu.com/12.04/serverguide/index.html).

Comment: As I mentioned in my OP, I am not very fluent yet.  I failed to mention I was already using the ubuntu desktop.  Why on the Win FTP?  Simply familiarity with it, and messing with vsftpd (which as I understand is fine out of the box for anonymous logins, but I wasn't looking to do that).  I actually have been reading much documentation, and being in a bit of a rush to get something as simple as a FTP server running, not all of it is sinking it.  I know it's not what Linux people like to hear, understandably so, my hope was just to start with something I was somewhat familiar with.

Comment: This will cause a MASSIVE disaster for you, and likely never work (normal users can not access ports below 1024)  simple ftp server that I can recommend is the one you already looked at. A decent [guide can be found](http://www.mmncs.com/2011/07/howto-install-setup-and-configure-basic-ftp-server-on-linux-ubuntu-11-04-using-vsftpd-service/) here.

Answer (score 0):

I pretty much agree with @Cumulus007

If you want GUI, use the ubuntu12.04 desktop instead, but not the server. Ubuntu server does not contain any graphical programs. Learning commands is very useful when you use linux though. When I was new to linux, I've never thought I can handle linux server at first glance. I thought this "box" is way smarter than me, and I still feel that way lol

However, since you have ubuntu server installed on your computer, you can get any type of GUI by installing xinit,openbox (tons of GUI are available in linux world, openbox is very minimum one), aterm (choose your favorite terminal program ex:gnome-terminal,terminator) ,and pcmanfm (light weight file manager)

login to your server
type

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get -y upgrade
```

// you may need to run this command if you haven't never run that before.

```
sudo apt-get install xinit openbox aterm

sudo init 6
```

// init 6 will reboot your computer

login to server again

type

```
startx
```

now you can get very minimum GUI.

There will be nothing display other than mouse cursor, just right click on anywhere. You will see the minimum menu. when you open up file manager (pcmanfm) you gonna say, it's missing icons!

sudo apt-get install lxde-icon-theme
//this will install icons.

I still recommend Ubuntu12.04 desktop for you. Consider using that.
Have fun!

Comment: Sorry I failed to mention I was already using the ubuntu desktop.  The reasoning is my unfamiliarity, and wracking my brain reading tons of documentation already, but not necessarily comprehending every little thing I am reading right now (since I am in a rush to get the FTP server up and running)  I thought it would be easier to work with something I am familiar with.  Thank you for your thoughtful post with these tips on the desktop though.  I thought if wine acted as a windows emulator, if I installed something with a GUI (on the ubuntu desktop) that I would be able to access the GUI.

Comment: Wine is not an emulator. You may be more comfortable with VirtualBox.